# Runtime Exception: "CoCreateInstanceEx: The specified service does not exist as an installed service."

Tags: windows, exception, dependencies, nsis

I just checked the latest source out of our repository after the installer (NSIS if it really matters) was created and a bug was discovered.

I started receiving the runtime exception `CoCreateInstanceEx: The specified service does not exist as an installed service.` on the following code:

```
Opc.IDiscovery discovery = new OpcCom.ServerEnumerator();
Opc.Server[] servers = discovery.GetAvailableServers(Opc.Specification.COM_DA_20);
```

Previous to creating the installer it seemed to work fine and this particular snippet of code hasn't been touched in weeks.

According to a quick search on the exception description, this probably has something to do with system drivers. But nothing has changed on the hardware (virtualized development system) and nothing has been installed since the check in where this code worked.

Any ideas on what caused this to break, and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hardware? This sounds like a COM DLL got unregistered - figure out what COM object is attempting to be instantiated and run regsvc32 on it.

Comment: That was it. Somehow I missed that I was running `MsiExec "redist.msi"` instead of `MsiExec /i "redist.msi"`